# What does abv mean on Monte carlo

Tags: fuse-panel, monte-carlo

What does the abbreviation ome or Meo mean on fuse panel labeled with left heated seat also it's an 2004 it starts for a min but will not stay running what's causing the theft deterrent kick in

Comment: It would be very helpful if you'd include in your question a picture of the fuse panel you're looking at. Use the "Edit" button below your question text, and then the "Moon and Mountains" button.